# I can't boot Windows after installing Kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, windows, dual-boot, grub

I've installed Kali Linux on a seperate partition, but forgot to register a user so I couldn't login. GRUB was installed correctly and I could boot both systems - Kali Linux (just couldn't login) and Windows 11.

So I installed Kali again, created a user and now I can't boot Windows. It shows up in GRUB, but if I try to start I'm just stuck at a black loading screen with a blue Windows logo.

Repairing, starting in safe mode, repairing with `bootrec` doesn't work either. Neither is starting with the Windows bootloader. Just bitdefender sometimes ask for the recovery key (secure boot is off).

Here's a screenshot of gparted, if that helps.

[image]

I'm a beginner, can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: [Here's advice from Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-boot-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-as/ef80e42c-27c4-4880-8cf2-84e543a487f8). Another possible solution is reinstalling Kali in EFI mode.

Comment: I'd suggest you re-think using Kali. As stated by [Kali devs](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/), _"Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution"_. Install a desktop distro; Debian or any of its derivatives teaches you relevant skills. Then run Kali as a VM. And [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs) is a **must**-read.

Comment: Relevant: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @Peregrino69 thanks but i did not ask which distro i should use. I know that Kali isn't for daily use or very beginner friendly. Just trying out all kind of different distros to see what is unique to some distros and what is useful in general. Can get 2 exams and lpic is one possible choice so i want to experiment a little bit. how reinstalling linux is fixing the problem? I've tried the things from the link, won't work. If I try bootrec /fixboot it says Access denied. If i I try to set the partition active it says "partition 3 isn't a MBR Hard drive, only MBR hard drives can be set to active"

Comment: I know you didn't, that's why I gave possible solutions first. Don't take it personally, friend - if you hang around a bit you'll see there's a lot of questions here posted by beginners installing Kali on hardware and running into all kinds of problems. You're obviously free to use whatever you like, it's just a friendly warning about future headaches :-)

Comment: This is more about Windows not booting than anything else. Grub sees Windws, transfers control to it and then Windows boots and gets stuck. Voting to move it to stackoverflow.